# How do I write an if statement in JSP-JSTL if I need to check whether the user list contains a specific user?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, jstl

'theGroup' and 'groupCreator' are a model(entity) attributes coming from the controller. 'users' is the array list which is the attribute of theGroup (theGroup.getUsers() basically).

I need to check if the groupCreator exists in theGroup.users list in JSP

I've tried the code below but it didn't work

```
<c:if test = "${theGroup.users.contains(groupCreator)}">

</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach` to iterate through values and then compare values in it with `groupCreator`. Your code will somewhat look like below  :

```
     <c:forEach var="values" items="${theGroup.users}">
        <c:if test="${values == groupCreator}">
            <!--setting true if value match-->
            <c:set var="Matched" value="true" scope="request" />
        </c:if>
     </c:forEach
     <!--Print-->
        ${Matched}
```